# Create Stripe Invoice Only if payment is successful

Tags: stripe-payments

Need help with Stripe payment process. I am using Stripe for payment but I want Stripe to create Invoice only if payment was successful. Current and default behavior of Stripe is that it first creates the invoice and then attempt for payment and if payment failed, marks the invoice void.

I don't really want invoice to be created if payment failed.

Help will he highly appreciated.

Regards
Kashif

I did go over Stripe official documents to see if we can control the invoice creation flow but can't find any lead on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Stripe Checkout, it supports creation of [post-payment invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts?payment-ui=checkout#paid-invoices).

With direct integration using Invoices, this is not possible. Payment can only be attempted once and Invoice is [created and finalized](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration#create-invoice-code).